How to preserve the original document's head tag when navigating in a turbo frame with `data-turbo-action='advance'`
The Problem:

I have a component that performs navigation using a turbo frame. I would like to reflect the navigation changes in the window URL for better UX.
According to the Turbo documentation, using data-turbo-action='advance' should change the history location and solve this issue.
However, the response document lacks the <head> tag. After the frame is loaded, all <meta> tags disappear from the document when they should be retained.

The Question:
How can I preserve the original document's <head> tag when navigating in a turbo frame with data-turbo-action='advance'?
Other Things I Tried to Reflect the Navigation in the Window URL:

Performing navigation from the turbo frame only, and then using JS with history.pushState({}, '', url). This did change the window URL, but when I tried to navigate to the previous page using the browser's "back" button, the URL changed but the new frame was not fetched and loaded.
Navigating with data-turbo-frame="_top" instead of data-turbo-action='advance', but this requires a lot of changes in the JS controller.

The Code:
Pagination component that is wrapped with turbo-frame tag:
// _pagination_component.html.slim

div data= { 'controller': 'pagination' }
    = turbo_frame_tag "pagination_turbo_frame#{pagination_id}",
                      data: { action: 'turbo:frame-load->pagination#frameLoaded' }
      = turbo_frame_tag :pagination_lazy_load_frame,
                        data: { 'pagination-target': 'container' }
         = yield
      = pagination_nav_component(pages_count, current_page, link_builder, distance_from_current_page:)

Inside the pagination component there is a nav component with links to navigate between pages:
// _pagination_nav_component.html.slim

nav id='pagination-nav'
  ul
    li
      a href=link_builder.call(page) data-turbo-action='advance'

The response:
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col h-100">
                <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column h-100">
                    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="h-100" data-controller="pagination">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-row h-100">
                                    <turbo-frame data-action="turbo:frame-load-&gt;pagination#frameLoaded" id="pagination_turbo_frame">
                                      ...
                                    </turbo-frame>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



Why is your controller rendering a "blank" document outline? I really think that's the culprit and not Turbo.

@max I assume that this is a result of an optimization that is done when the controller renders a full page like index and then the following headers are present in the request: X-Turbo-Request-Id & Turbo-Frame. Does that make any sense? because it doesn't happen when a controller renders partial.

I can't reproduce it in a vanilla rails app so it seems more like an issue with your non-standard setup.
